# how to perform bulk update with change check in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel, I am using this code in the update function. works fine, but is it possible to save lines of code with bulk insertion?

Example: $product->update($request->all());

But first check if they have sent new data to update.

My Function Update:

```
 public function update(ProductUpdateRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $data = Product::findOrFail($product->id);
    $data->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $data->name_product = $request->name_product;
    $data->description = $request->description;
    $data->stock = $request->stock;
    $data->price_buy = $request->price_buy;
    $data->price_sale = $request->price_sale;
    $data->status = $request->status;

    if ($data->isDirty()) {
        $data->update($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            'color' => 'green',
            'message' => 'CATEGORY EDIT'
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'color' => 'red',
            'message' => 'NO CHANGE DETECTED'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fill()` method to fill the model with data without committing to database. Do the dirty check and then save. Eg:

```
public function update(ProductUpdateRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $product->fill($request->all()); //no need to use product->find since $product with the id is already injected

    if ($product->isDirty()) {
        $product->update($request->all()); //or use $product->save(); since model is alraedy filled with new data
        return response()->json([
            'color' => 'green',
            'message' => 'CATEGORY EDIT'
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'color' => 'red',
            'message' => 'NO CHANGE DETECTED'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Do note that `save` method actually checks if the model is dirty. So, if you do not want to send custom messages based on whether the model was changed or not, you could just call `save()` instead of `update()` without the dirty check.